# How to add a second content section when using certain page template

Tags: custom-content

Is it possible to enable a second content area in the edit screen if a certain template is chosen?

I have seen plugins like the second section plugin but that enables it for all pages I would like to only have the second section if a certain page template is chosen for a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [add a metabox](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for your second content section, then hide it with a bit of javascript if the current template isn't a specific template:

```
current_template = jQuery('#page_template').val();
if( current_template != 'my-special-template.php' ){
    jQuery('#_your_meta_box_id').hide();
}
```

then bind a function to the change event of the template dropdown and show it when a specific template is selected:

```
jQuery('#page_template').change(function(){
    selected_template = jQuery(this).val();
    if( selected_template == 'my-special-template.php' ){
        jQuery('#_your_meta_box_id').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that is a nice idea, my only concern would be users without JavaScript on.

Comment: @Lee - without javascript the only way to do it would be to require that they select a template then save the post before they're able to see the additional content section. the visual editor doesn't work and there's no way to add images to a post without js anyway.

Comment: |Good point I will try it out and see how I get on - thanks :)